# Correct approach for updating an already rendered ReactJS component from outside that component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS components within an AngularJS app.

In one of my controllers, I have the following logic which renders an `OrdersTable` component.

```
  var search = $location.search();
  var page = search.hasOwnProperty('page') ? search.page : 0;
  var sort = search.hasOwnProperty('sort') ? search.sort : 'number,desc';

  var r = React.createFactory(OrdersTable);
  var component = React.render(r({
    ordersSummaryFn: OrderService.ordersSummary,
    page: page,
    sort: sort
  }), document.querySelector('.order-wrapper'));
```

When a user clicks on the pagination links on the page, the query string changes.  My route configuration has `reloadOnSearch` set to `false` and my controller contains the following code to listen to a query string change.

```
  $scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function() {
    search = $location.search();
    page = search.hasOwnProperty('page') ? search.page : 0;
    sort = search.hasOwnProperty('sort') ? search.sort : 'number,desc';
    component.pageOrders(page, sort);
  });
```

So when the page and sort query parameters change, I'm calling the `pageOrders` method directly on the component returned in the initial rendering of the component.  This method performs an ajax call to the server and then updates the state of the `OrdersTable` component, which in turn causes the component to re-render.

I'm wondering if this is the correct approach to update/re-render a component after it's been mounted if I'm listening for an event to be fired outside of the react component.  It just seems that the `component.pageOrders(page, sort)` call isn't the correct way to do this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the component probably doesn't need state.  If you manage the http requests in angular, then the react component is simpler and easier to reuse.

```
var containerTarget = document.querySelector('.order-wrapper');

// idempotent update function
function update(props){
    React.render(React.createElement(OrdersTable, props), containerTarget);
}

var fetchDataAndUpdate = function(){
    var search = $location.search();
    var page = search.hasOwnProperty('page') ? search.page : 0;
    var sort = search.hasOwnProperty('sort') ? search.sort : 'number,desc';
    OrderService.ordersSummary({
        page: page,
        sort: sort
    }).then(function(results){
        update({data: results, page: page, sort: sort});
    });    
};

fetchDataAndUpdate();
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', fetchDataAndUpdate);

// optionally do an initial render before you have data
update({});
```

You can also pass it callbacks for when a column header, or pagination button is clicked, and react accordingly in angular.

Comment: Looks pretty straight forward.  Since I'm fairly new to React, in your example you have `React.render(React.createElement(OrdersTable, props), containerTarget);`.  During the first pass, this creates the component.  Through subsequent passes afterwards, does React merely update the existing component?  It's not clear to me if the component is recreated every time, or just created once and then updated.

Comment: Got around to trying this out today and it works great :)  Thanks for your help!